# Collapsing my page upon resizing

Tags: html, css

I have created [this page](http://www.ayaami.com/site/freebook) and it is working fine, I'm having issue regarding the resizing, when I do resize the browser my page cropped and couldn't scroll to reach it.
 This is my HTML Code

```
  <body id="page-top">
    <style type="text/css">

  @media (min-width:1500px) { 


   .new_bg {
    background-image: url(img/bg2000.png);
    background-size: cover;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 50%;
  }

}
```

in my CSS code:

```
html,body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}
```

Apologize if I didn't catch the needed portion of code, you may refer for the page to try, thanks.

**UPDATE**
[image: That is how it does look when I resize my page, part of it cropped.[![][2]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVamX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you page CSS,

```
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
     header{
         display:none;
     }
 }
```

This is causing your page to go invisible when you resize your window. When you start resizing your window, at some width and height, the orientation is becoming as portrait and whole page is set to `display:none`.

Based on your question, I feel like, you don't need that style, as your query was like you are unable to find the content on resize.

***Update***

Your `.header-content` style is having `-webkit-transform:TranslateY()` and `transform:translateY()`.

This is making your content to move up and making your page start position outside the browser view. Please remove these two.

Your header-content is having ***padding*** values, making your main content to move some pixels to the right. This is causing overflow. Please remove this as well.

Comment: I removed this part, I was trying to restrict the users for landscape mode only for tablets. I need to prevent them from having a smaller screen because in certain cases my content goes out of the screen.

Comment: you have some additional overflow space across your page. If you could control that, you will be able to load page in landscape also without any issue.

Comment: May you specify where exactly? appreciated.

Comment: checking the same.. I will try to find that, meanwhile you can also try from your end.

Comment: I updated the post, my logo and entire content goes up.

Comment: Yes that works, I removed the class because of translateY and it worked, thanks alot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94310/discussion-between-malli1246-and-sadiq-jaffer).

Comment: Please mark as answered, if it solved all your issues

Answer (score 0):

```
  @media (max-width:1500px) { 


   .new_bg {
    background-image: url(img/bg2000.png);
    background-size: cover;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 50%;
  }

}
```

change min width to max width try thiss...

Comment: My need is to prevent user from resizing more so they don't get small page, this width for my media query.